# What is this stepped design/component called?

Tags: mobile, design-patterns, design, terminology, component

I search for flow builder or sequence but can't seem to find references on google.

This is the layout:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This element is a **[vertical stepper](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html)**

Here's a [Material UI](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) reference as well.

Comment: ah! thanks Mike!

Comment: What would you call the actions like "Send Message" which can be optionally added under each step? Is there a name for these types of components? I'd guess they might be classified by their interactive nature (drag/drop, click to remove, click child to edit)